# Multiple post requests were sent to the same URL with different bodies

Tags: flutter, http

I'm trying to send 4 requests to the same url in a post http request in Flutter but it's giving me timeout exception after(whatever time out I passed in the request) Future not complete.

I'm using tenda router, tvBox and SonnOff.

```
await http.post(
                    Uri.parse('http://192.168.1.2:8081/zeroconf/monitor'),
                    body: jsonEncode({
                      "deviceid": '10016b7046',
                      "data": {
                        "subDevId": '3d18474c3831311947313130',
                        "outlet": 0,
                        "time": 1
                      }
                    })).timeout(Duration(seconds: 5)).then((value) {
                  print(value.body);
               
                });
```

Comment: try to send request with Post man , then if not worked. tell the backend dev there is problem

Comment: it's a personal project there's no backend dev. it's giving me response once and then gives nothing no matter how many times i made a request. where do you think the problem.